# PDFJs in .NET MAUI WebView on iOS

Tags: ios, .net, webview, pdf.js

I'm trying to use PDFJs in a WebView to load a locally stored file in the apps data directory. It works fine on my iOS simulator, however, once I put the build into TestFlight and test on a real device, PDFJs loads and throws exception `missing_file_error`.

I have added the following to my `MauiProgram.cs`:

```
#if IOS || MACCATALYST
if (handler.PlatformView is WKWebView wkWebView)
{
    wkWebView.Configuration.Preferences.SetValueForKey(Foundation.NSObject.FromObject(true), new NSString("allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"));
    wkWebView.Configuration.Preferences.SetValueForKey(Foundation.NSObject.FromObject(false), new NSString("secureContextChecksEnabled"));
    wkWebView.Configuration.Preferences.SetValueForKey(Foundation.NSObject.FromObject(true), new NSString("fileSystemAccessEnabled"));
    wkWebView.Configuration.Preferences.SetValueForKey(Foundation.NSObject.FromObject(true), new NSString("storageAPIEnabled"));
}
#endif
```

The following to my `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```